# Placing images in a row using CSS3 & best practises

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I'm really new to HTML5 and CSS3 and my searches haven't turned up anything to what I'm sure is a really basic thing. What I'm trying to do is create a row of clickable images / links for my website. Much like how stack overflow has there questions, tags users links above.

So far my css looks like the following:

```
a#header { 
    display:block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: none;
    background: url('img url') no-repeat bottom;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;    
}
```

But this isn't doing what I'm after. It's only placing the image in the centre of the screen. Could someone please help me? Also, is there a best practise for doing something like this?

Comment: Try removing `margin: 0 auto;` and changing the display value of `a#header` to `inline-block` and then use `text-align: center;` on the parent container.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Does `a#header` refer to the header that contains all the links? Or is it supposed to refer to the links themselves? Providing a bit of sample HTML might help clear things up.

Comment: In your code, `a#header` refers to a link with the id header. e.g. `<a href="#" id="header"></a>` If you want to target all links with a header element, change your code to `#header a{ }`

Answer (score 1):

The `margin:0 auto` is what is putting it in the center of the screen. You will probably want to drop this, or put it on the container element rather than the individual boxes.

What you probably want for putting several boxes in a line is either `float:left` or `display:inline-block`. Either of these will work; they work differently, and there are things you need to know about both of them in order to get the layout working the way you want it, but I'll leave those extra details for you to do further research on.

It's worth noting that none of the code you quoted is specific to HTML5 or CSS3 -- it's all basic HTML/CSS syntax that has been around for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any markup, I'll use the stackoverflow example you cited:

```
<div class="nav mainnavs ">
    <ul>
        <li class="youarehere"><a href="/questions" id="nav-questions">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tags" id="nav-tags">Tags</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users" id="nav-users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="/help/badges" id="nav-badges">Badges</a></li>
        <li><a href="/unanswered" id="nav-unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

While you could use your own divs to do this markup, this is the most semantic and concise way of representing a navigation list.

To style this list the way you want, you only need to apply the following styles:

```
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    /* Any other styles to disable text decoration, etc. */
}
```

Then just position the `.nav` container where ever you want on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/MRayW/6/

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_0">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_1">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_2">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_3">d</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_4">e</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_5">f</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="header_6">g</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
a[id^='header_'] {
    border: none;
    background: url('xxx.jpg') no-repeat bottom;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
    list-style:none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 420px;
}

nav {
    margin:0 auto
    width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy like me, you can put a few `<a>` tags in a `<header>` or `<nav>`, and use `display: inline-block`.

http://jsbin.com/ivevey/3/edit

HTML

```
<header>
  <a href></a>
  <a href></a>
  <a href></a>
  <a href></a>
  <a href></a>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
  text-align: center;
}

header > a { /* assuming a <header> contains your <a> tags */
    display: inline-block; /* make sure every image/link is treated like text, ltr */

    width: 15px; /* width/height or padding. either works */
    height: 15px; 

    background-color: red; /* This should work for a 15px x 15px image instead */
}
```

Just be careful of the space between the links. Those are whitespace characters. I generally use `header {font-size: 0;}` to clear that up.

Ideally, I'd have a structure where there's a `<ul>` in a `<nav>`, since it is a *list of navigation links*, after all.